# Apache POI replacing values inside exampleRow without changing the row itself

Tags: java, json, apache-poi

I have a method which replaces all the occurrences of some JSON object keys inside. The method has 2 arguments - a JSON object and a row to replace. Here it is:

```
private XWPFTableRow replaceTextInARow(XWPFTableRow row, JSONObject jsonObjectToFindKeysIn) 
{
    XWPFTableRow copyOfOriginalRaw = new XWPFTableRow(row.getCtRow(), row.getTable());
    
    for (XWPFTableCell cell : copyOfOriginalRaw.getTableCells()) {
         for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
            for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) 
            {
            String text = r.getText(0);
              if (text != null && jsonObjectToFindKeysIn.has(text))
              {
                  text = text.replace(text, jsonObjectToFindKeysIn.getString(text));
                  r.setText(text, 0);
              }
            }
         }
      }
    
    return copyOfOriginalRaw;
}
```

And it works so well. I made a copy of the original row for a reason - I do not want to replace the original row - set this row to this value, if needed instead.

However, in this case it does not seem to work:

```
XWPFTableRow exampleRow = tableToCreateRowsIn.getRow(tableToCreateRowsIn.getRows().size() - 2);

      for(int i = 0; i < allSections.length(); i++) 
      {
          System.out.println(exampleRow.getCell(0).getText());
          JSONObject particularSection = allSections.getJSONObject(i);
          XWPFTableRow replacedTableRow = replaceTextInARow(exampleRow, particularSection);
          tableToCreateRowsIn.addRow(replacedTableRow, i + 2);
      }
```

Here's I have a example row which looks like this:

[image]

I want to use this example for every JSON object inside the array. However, after the very first iteration in the loop, exampleRow becomes absolutely different - every print since then becomes substituted value inside the loop.
And it gives me a number of rows, based on length of allSection array. But they are all the same, since exampleRow has changed.I want it to be immutable. What's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a complete code in the question so not a complete answer possible. But using `row.getCtRow()` you are getting the underlying `CTRow` object of the original row. If you are using this in the copied row, both rows will have the same underlaying object which holds the XML having the text runs in it. You need cloning the `CTRow` object. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235410/java-apache-poi-word-existing-table-insert-row-with-cell-style-and-formatting/46236650 for examples on how to.

Comment: I am sorry, but what do you mean by "incomplete code"?

Comment: I am not a friend of "I suspect..." and "Try this..." answers so I always will provide **tested** [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in my answers. But this is not possible here since not a `mcve` in the question. But I've told you my suspicion in the comment. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it actually did the trick, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found  Axel Richter's comment very useful.
So, I have rewritten the method. Now it looks like this:

```
private XWPFTableRow replaceTextInARow(XWPFTableRow row, JSONObject richJSON, boolean createCopy) throws XmlException, IOException 
{
    XWPFTableRow copyOfOriginalRaw;

    if(createCopy) // if we want our original table row to remain intact
    {
    copyOfOriginalRaw = new XWPFTableRow(CTRow.Factory.parse(row.getCtRow().newInputStream()), row.getTable());
    }
    else copyOfOriginalRaw = row; // otherwise we replace text in the original row

    for (XWPFTableCell cell : copyOfOriginalRaw.getTableCells()) {
         for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
            for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) 
            {
            String text = r.getText(0);             
              if (text != null && richJSON.has(text))
              {
                  if(!richJSON.getString(text).isEmpty()) 
                  {
                  text = text.replace(text, richJSON.getString(text));
                  r.setText(text, 0);
                  }
                  else r.setText("-", 0);
              }
            }
         }
      }
    return copyOfOriginalRaw;
}
```

I have also added an extra argument. It makes the method really versatile - in this case we can choose whether we want to make changes to the original table row or create a copy instead. Thanks.