# Can't change row text in .docx file once row is added to table

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I have the problem with the following code:

```
XWPFTable table = <get table somehow>;
CTRow firstRow = table.getRow(0).getCtRow();

for (int i = 0; i < data.getRowCount(); i++) {
    CTRow ctRow = (CTRow) firstRow.copy();
    XWPFTableRow row = new XWPFTableRow(ctRow, table);
    XWPFRun[] cellRuns = row.getTableCells()
            .stream()
            .map(c -> c.getParagraphs().get(0))
            .map(p -> p.getRuns().isEmpty() ? p.createRun() : p.getRuns().get(0))
            .toArray(XWPFRun[]::new);
    for (int j = 0; j < cellRuns.length; j++) {
        cellRuns[j].setText(data.getValueAt(i, j).toString(), 0);
    }
    table.addRow(row);
}


table.getRow(1).getTableCells()
.get(0).getParagraphs()
.get(0).getRuns()
.get(0).setText("FooBar", 0); //change text in some added row
```

This code is copying the first row of the table several times and then copying values from `data`. Works perfectly fine (except text style) except the last operator, which was supposed to change the text in some added table row. Also, the "FooBar" string doesn't even appear in document.xml of created WORD document. I failed to see any clues from debug, because it seems, that `table.addRow(row);` operator just copies `row` pointer to it's internal list of rows. Also, I didn't have problems with altering already existing rows. So do you have any ideas why this could happen?

Comment: Why don't you try changing your row text (to the "FooBar") in the inner _for loop_ using an _if condition_ while setting the text to the cellRuns[] array?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235410/java-apache-poi-word-existing-table-insert-row-with-cell-style-and-formatting/46236650#46236650: Read second paragraph in my answer.

Comment: @Abhinav, I already did this, but I really want to understand what is wrong with the code. It doesn't seem right, cause when I change the existing row, it works. Also, values actually change in debugger after adding, theese changes just are not saved in the docx.

Comment: @Astralogics Ktt Would you please edit your question properly by pasting the complete code so that we can better understanding of your problem?

Comment: @Abhinav, there is similar code in link in Axel Richter's comment. Moving `table.addRow(newRow, 2);` instruction to `newRow` declaration should reproduce the problem

Comment: @Axel Richter, is that just your observation or it is documented? Cause I haven't found info about this issue in apache docs yet

Comment: Documented? Such an issue in a project like `apache poi`? You are kidding me! ;-). But see my answer.

Comment: @Axel Richter, ok, thanks. But your answer is just saying "it happens because it happens". I thought, there could be involved some obvious peculiarity of xmlbeans, but I guess I'll just put up with it.

Comment: On stackoverflow there are multiple answers to a question possible. So as said in my answer, maybe another user here may be able determining the exact reason and providing another answer.

Comment: @Axel Richter with such activity on `apache-poi` tag, unlikely. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reproducing the problem do having a `source.docx` having a first table having at least two rows.

Then do running following code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTRow;

public class WordInsertTableRow {

 static XWPFTableRow insertNewTableRow(XWPFTableRow sourceTableRow, int pos) throws Exception {
  XWPFTable table = sourceTableRow.getTable();
  CTRow newCTRrow = CTRow.Factory.parse(sourceTableRow.getCtRow().newInputStream());
  XWPFTableRow tableRow = new XWPFTableRow(newCTRrow, table);
  table.addRow(tableRow, pos);
  return tableRow;
 }

 static void commitTableRows(XWPFTable table) {
  int rowNr = 0;
  for (XWPFTableRow tableRow : table.getRows()) {
   table.getCTTbl().setTrArray(rowNr++, tableRow.getCtRow());
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("source.docx"));
  boolean weMustCommitTableRows = false;

  XWPFTable table = doc.getTableArray(0);

  // insert new row, which is a copy of row 2, as new row 3:
  XWPFTableRow sourceTableRow = table.getRow(1);
  XWPFTableRow newRow3 = insertNewTableRow(sourceTableRow, 2);

  // now changing something in that new row:
  int i = 1;
  for (XWPFTableCell cell : newRow3.getTableCells()) {
   for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
    for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
     run.setText("New row 3 run " + i++, 0);
    }
   }
  }
System.out.println(newRow3.getCtRow()); // was changed
System.out.println(table.getRow(2).getCtRow()); // even this is changed
System.out.println(table.getCTTbl().getTrArray(2)); // but this was not changed, why not?
  weMustCommitTableRows = true;

  if (weMustCommitTableRows) commitTableRows(table); // now it is changed

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}
```

This code creates a copy of second row and inserts it as third row in the table. Then it does changing something in that new third row.

The issue ist, that the changings do appearing in low level `CTRow` of the row itself but do not appearing in low Level `CTTbl` of the table. For me this is not logically and I cannot get the reason of that. It looks as if the new `CTRow` elements are not part of the `CTTbl` at all. But they were added to it using `ctTbl.setTrArray` in [XWPFTable.addRow](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_0_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.java?view=markup#l1041). So I suspect there is something wrong with `setTrArray` in `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTbl`. It seems updating the `XML` correctly but losing the object relations in the array  (or list) of `CTRow`s in `CTTbl`. But this is very hard to determining because of the kind of programming the `org.openxmlformats.schemas` classes. At least I was not able to do so. Maybe another of the professional and enthusiast programmers here may be able?

I am using the same approach for inserting rows having tthe same styling as a given source row. But after I have done this, I am setting `boolean weMustCommitTableRows = true;` and then I am doing `if (weMustCommitTableRows) commitTableRows(table);` before writing out the document. Then all changings will be committed.

Comment: 1. Thank you for your "commitTableRows()" recipe. It helps.

Comment: 2. I filed an issue for Apache XmlBeans project regarding this. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-533