# Apache POI: modify row after it was already added to the table

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

Consider `.docx` with **1 row, 1 column** table. I want to copy the row, and fill the copied row with some text.

The following works fine:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
XWPFTable table = document.getTables().get(0);
XWPFTableRow templateRow = table.getRow(0);
XWPFTableRow copiedTemplateRow = new XWPFTableRow((CTRow) templateRow.getCtRow().copy(), table);
copiedTemplateRow.getTableCells().get(0).setText("SOME TEXT");
table.addRow(copiedTemplateRow);
```

However, I'd prefer to *first* `addRow`, and then modify it, like so:

```
table.addRow(copiedTemplateRow);
copiedTemplateRow.getTableCells().get(0).setText("SOME TEXT");
```

However in this second version, when saving to docx, the row is not modified like I expected.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211749/cant-change-row-text-in-docx-file-once-row-is-added-to-table/53246880#53246880

Comment: Thank you, I can accept your answer if you like.