# POI Word Unable to merge newly created cell vertically

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, row, cell

I know how to merge cells vertically with Apache POI word. But it seems if a new row is created, the merge won't take effect.

Here is the input table:

[image]

I wish to add a new row between `old row 2` and `old row 3`, and have the new row's cell at first column merged into C2, like this:

[image: ![picture 2]

So I created a new row and added it to the table below `old row 2`, and attempt to merge the cells

github source code [link is here](https://github.com/peckwood/stackoverflow-question-code-67830373), it can reproduce the problem.

```
public class POIWordAddSubRowQuestionDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlException{
        ClassLoader classLoader = POIWordAddSubRowQuestionDemo.class.getClassLoader();
        InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("input.docx");
        String outputDocxPath = "F:/TEMP/output.docx";
        assert inputStream != null;
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
        XWPFTable table = doc.getTables().get(0);
        //this is 'old row 2'
        XWPFTableRow secondRow = table.getRows().get(1);

        //create a new row that is based on 'old row 2'
        CTRow ctrow = CTRow.Factory.parse(secondRow.getCtRow().newInputStream());
        XWPFTableRow newRow = new XWPFTableRow(ctrow, table);
        XWPFRun xwpfRun = newRow.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns().get(0);
        //set row text
        xwpfRun.setText("new row", 0);
        // add new row below 'old row 2'
        table.addRow(newRow, 2);

        //merge cells at first column of 'old row 2', 'new row', and 'old row 3'
        mergeCellVertically(doc.getTables().get(0), 0, 1, 3);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputDocxPath);
        doc.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }

    static void mergeCellVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int fromRow, int toRow) {
        for(int rowIndex = fromRow; rowIndex <= toRow; rowIndex++) {
            XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(col);
            CTVMerge vmerge = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
            if(rowIndex == fromRow){
                // The first merged cell is set with RESTART merge value
                vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
            } else {
                // Cells which join (merge) the first one, are set with CONTINUE
                vmerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
                // and the content should be removed
                for (int i = cell.getParagraphs().size(); i > 0; i--) {
                    cell.removeParagraph(0);
                }
                cell.addParagraph();
            }
            // Try getting the TcPr. Not simply setting an new one every time.
            CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
            if (tcPr == null) tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
            tcPr.setVMerge(vmerge);
        }
    }
}
```

But the merge did not work and I got:

[image: ![picture 3]

In another attempt, I tried to merge based on the table in picture 3 to get the table in picture 2, and it was a success. The only difference between the 2 attempts is that `new row` was not newly created, but rather read from the docx document, so I believe creating a new row was the reason why merge failed.

So is there a solution for merging newly created rows? I really don't want to split this operation like this: adding rows > saving docx to disk> read docx from disk> merge rows.

Comment: @AxelRichter You are right. To make it clear, I wrote a example and uploaded it to github, the link is https://github.com/peckwood/stackoverflow-question-code-67830373. The images was drawn with Paint by me, so I replaced them with actual Word screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is not with `mergeCellVertically` method but with your approach to copy table row. When copying the underlying `CTRow` and inserting it in `CTTbl.TrArray` using `XWPFTable.addRow` it must be fully complete. Later changings are not written in `XML`. I told that in my answer [java Apache POI Word existing table insert row with cell style and formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235410/java-apache-poi-word-existing-table-insert-row-with-cell-style-and-formatting/46236650#46236650) already. And I provided a method `commitTableRows` in my answer [Can't change row text in .docx file once row is added to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211749/cant-change-row-text-in-docx-file-once-row-is-added-to-table/53246880#53246880). This method needs to be called before writing out the document, so the later changes get written in `XML`.

So because you are copying second row, which is the start of merging, that setting also gets copied. And the later called `mergeCellVertically` does not take effect. So your `newRow` remains new start of merging. This is what you get.

So after all changes and before writing out, call `commitTableRows`.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;


public class WordInsertTableRowAndMerge {
    
 static XWPFTableRow insertNewTableRow(XWPFTableRow sourceTableRow, int pos) throws Exception {
  XWPFTable table = sourceTableRow.getTable();
  CTRow newCTRrow = CTRow.Factory.parse(sourceTableRow.getCtRow().newInputStream());
  XWPFTableRow tableRow = new XWPFTableRow(newCTRrow, table);
  table.addRow(tableRow, pos);
  return tableRow;
 }

 static void commitTableRows(XWPFTable table) {
  int rowNr = 0;
  for (XWPFTableRow tableRow : table.getRows()) {
   table.getCTTbl().setTrArray(rowNr++, tableRow.getCtRow());
  }
 }
    
 static void mergeCellVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int fromRow, int toRow) {
  for(int rowIndex = fromRow; rowIndex <= toRow; rowIndex++) {
   System.out.println("rowIndex: " + rowIndex);
   XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(col);
   CTVMerge vmerge = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
   if(rowIndex == fromRow){
    // The first merged cell is set with RESTART merge value
    vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
   } else {
    // Cells which join (merge) the first one, are set with CONTINUE
    vmerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
    // and the content should be removed
    for (int i = cell.getParagraphs().size(); i > 0; i--) {
     cell.removeParagraph(0);
    }
    cell.addParagraph();
   }
   // Try getting the TcPr. Not simply setting an new one every time.
   CTTcPr tcPr = cell.getCTTc().getTcPr();
   if (tcPr == null) tcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
   tcPr.setVMerge(vmerge);
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./source.docx"));
  
  XWPFTable table = doc.getTables().get(0);

  XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(1);
  XWPFTableRow newRow = insertNewTableRow(row, 2);
  
  XWPFTableCell cell = newRow.getCell(0); if (cell == null) cell = newRow.addNewTableCell();
  // not needed because merged to cell above
  cell = newRow.getCell(1); if (cell == null) cell = newRow.addNewTableCell();
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) { // only use first text runs in paragraphs
   for (int r = paragraph.getRuns().size()-1; r >= 0; r--) {
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.getRuns().get(r);
    if (r == 0) {
     run.setText("new row 1", 0);
    } else {
     paragraph.removeRun(r); 
    }
   }
  }

  mergeCellVertically(table, 0, 1, 3);

  commitTableRows(table);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./result.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: I tried `commitTableRows` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA approach you might like to adapt. It inserts a new row between rows 3 & 4:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  .Cell(4, 2).Range.InsertBreak (wdColumnBreak)
  .Rows.Add
  .Cell(2, 1).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(4, 1)
  .Range.Characters.Last.Next.Delete
  .Cell(2, 1).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(5, 1)
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```