# Add rows dynamically in a XWPF copying other row (APACHE POI)

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

I would like to have a function for an XWPFTable that uses Word to dynamically copy rows.

With the word dynamically I mean to copy the value of the cell above and the element number to be able to replace it with the value that I will change later. I am using the Apache POI library

For example, in a row I will have #POR1# in cell x, which will be the percentage of the first element, I want to create a row just after I have #POR2# in cell so that I can then substitute the values

I found a similar function for Excel, but I didn't find it for Word

```java
private static void copyRow(Workbook workbook, Sheet worksheet, int sourceRowNum, int destinationRowNum, int contadorDinamico) {
    Row newRow = worksheet.getRow(destinationRowNum);
    Row sourceRow = worksheet.getRow(sourceRowNum);

    if (newRow != null) {
        worksheet.shiftRows(destinationRowNum, worksheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);
    }
    newRow = worksheet.createRow(destinationRowNum);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        Cell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(i);
        Cell newCell = newRow.createCell(i);

        if (oldCell == null) {
            newCell = null;
            continue;
        }

        // Copy style from old cell and apply to new cell
        CellStyle newCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
        ;
        newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);

        // If there is a cell comment, copy
        if (oldCell.getCellComment() != null) {
            newCell.setCellComment(oldCell.getCellComment());
        }

        // If there is a cell hyperlink, copy
        if (oldCell.getHyperlink() != null) {
            newCell.setHyperlink(oldCell.getHyperlink());
        }

        // Set the cell data type
        newCell.setCellType(oldCell.getCellType());

        if(oldCell.getStringCellValue() != null) {
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue().contains("#") ? oldCell.getStringCellValue().substring(0, oldCell.getStringCellValue().length()-2) + contadorDinamico + oldCell.getStringCellValue().substring(oldCell.getStringCellValue().length()-1, oldCell.getStringCellValue().length()) : oldCell.getStringCellValue());
        }
        
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < worksheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
        CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = worksheet.getMergedRegion(i);
        if (cellRangeAddress.getFirstRow() == sourceRow.getRowNum()) {
            CellRangeAddress newCellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(newRow.getRowNum(),
                    (newRow.getRowNum() +
                            (cellRangeAddress.getLastRow() - cellRangeAddress.getFirstRow()
                                    )),
                    cellRangeAddress.getFirstColumn(),
                    cellRangeAddress.getLastColumn());
            worksheet.addMergedRegion(newCellRangeAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235410/java-apache-poi-word-existing-table-insert-row-with-cell-style-and-formatting/46236650#46236650 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211749/cant-change-row-text-in-docx-file-once-row-is-added-to-table/53246880#53246880